# convert list to string then back it to list [ Python]

Tags: python, edit, strip

I got a problem, it's about converting from List to String to edit it

I have file text content these name

```
Roby
Bucky
johan
```

Then I want to add beside each one `OK:1`

so i do this code

```
Names='a.txt' # here is the names
O=open(Names,'r') # we open the file content the names
iamList=O.readlines() # read the name it would be List !
imSting=str(iamList) # convert it to string
Edit=imSting.replace(r"\n","Ok:1") # Editing by adding
noname=Edit
noname=noname.split()
for PT in noname:
    PT.strip('[')
    print PT
```

and i got this result
`['RobyOk:1',
'BuckyOk:1',
'johan']`
i want to delete these thing `[ , '`
i tried `strip` and `replace('[','')`

any ideas ?

Comment: You almost never want to convert a piece of data from a single string, to a list, back to a string, then back to a list (only to convert it back to a string once again for output.  Try to operate on the most original version of the data possible, (in your case, the output of `readlines` is probably ideal), and only downgrade it at the end.  basically, get rid of the `str()`,  you don't need it and it's giving you more trouble than it can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to a string to add `Ok:1` at the end of each element.

You could do it with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
iamNewList = [e.rstrip() + 'Ok:1' for e in iamList]
```

Alternatively, to be less fancy, you could do this:

```
iamNewList = []
for e in iamList:
    iamNewList.append(e.rstrip() + 'Ok:1')
```

Note, [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) strips all whitespace, such as newlines, off of the end of the string, which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Since he fills `iamList` from a call to `readlines`, your code will have the `"Ok:1"` after the line break, not before it.

Answer (score 1):

**solution:**

```
f = open('a.txt')
names = [line.strip() + 'Ok:1' for line in f.readlines()]
f.close()
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

I used 'line.strip()', because the os.linesep (generally '\n') can be different than the line-seperation used in your file, leaving each line still with a '\n'.

About your approach:
Because iamList was a List, the representation of that List created by str(iamList)
already contained the brackets '[' and the commas ',': 
these are part of the string representation.
`print('imSting: ' + imSting)` will show this.
So you could have replaced the '\n' by 'Ok:1' right from imSting and spliting the
new string into a list over the ', ' part:

`(imSting.replace(r"\n", 'Ok:1')[2:-2] + 'Ok:1').split("', '")`

The `[2:-2]` only returns the characters between ['  and ']  thus effectively removing the brackets.

The first solution could almost be a one-liner and is much easier to read, and therefore much more 'Pythonic'.
However, making a habit of closing the file after reading is better.

Answer (score 0):

`iamList = O.readlines()` will give you a list.

**You do NOT want to convert that list to a string. Avoid string manipulation at all costs; it's bad coding practice.** (For this reason, I am also concerned about the reason you're adding `'Ok:1'` to each string.)

Instead, just do `[x+' OKAY!' for x in yourFile.read().splitlines()]`

However you should say why you want to add "Ok:1", because it seems likely you're going about something the wrong way. *You should say what you're actually trying to do.*

Comment: `readlines` does not strip line endings so if `x` is "Roby" then `x+' OKAY!'` will result in `"Roby\nOKAY!".

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work. The last line has no line break at the end, so you don't have "Ok:1" in there.

Try this:

```
[b.replace("\n","") + "Ok:1" for b in open("C:\\py\\a.txt","r")]
```

"Expanded" version:

```
newList = []
for b in open("C:\\py\\a.txt","r"):
  newList.append(b.replace("\n","") + "Ok:1")
```

Comment: i don't get it ,,, well the last line problem it's easy to fix via adding new line at the list or edit it ,,, but the problem with `[ , '`

Comment: Thats because of your list to string shenanigans.  My line of code is a list comprehension.

Comment: Since he fills iamList from a call to readlines, your code will have the "Ok:1" after the line break, not before it.

Comment: he never says he wants to write it back to a filem so I just replaced them.

Comment: This works by reading each line from the file (since iterating over an open file automatically returns the content line-by-line), it then removes the newlines where they exist, which for the last line it may or it may not, and finally, it adds the extra text.  By doing the newline replacement in a separate step from the append, it solves the trailing newline issue.